# could not use click event when using cfilebrowserwidget

Tags: jquery, yii, widget, yii-extensions

I am using the cfilebroweserwidget(http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cfilebrowserwidget/) for my yii application. I use the widge to show the filesystem of my uploads directory. However, I need to do something when a directory is click on the file browser. But I cannot add another jquery code to check if the folder link is click. I already check on the accompanying js file and comment out the line below so that the click event will not be prevented.

```
if( o.folderEvent.toLowerCase != 'click' ) 
    $(t).find('LI A').bind('click', function() { 
        return false; 
});
```

But still I cannot add a code to check a link is click.
What are the other ways to check the codes that could prevent the click event to be trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem. The problem was the code that I have for the click is not bind to the link element generated by the widget because it will recreate the the link everytime a directory is click. So I add the click code on the file browser connector, the code where it recreate the file structure. Hope this hope someone.